# I updated my material_floating_search_bar package to material_floating_search_bar_2

Tags: android, flutter, windows, dart

**I am getting error in systemOverlayStyle here. Please help me

The error is:
The named parameter 'systemOverlayStyle' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'systemOverlayStyle'. **

Code:

```
return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: FloatingSearchAppBar(
        liftOnScrollElevation: 0.0,
        elevation: fullWeather == null ? 2.0 : 0.0,
        systemOverlayStyle: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.systemOverlayStyle,
        automaticallyImplyBackButton: false,
        controller: controller,
        progress: fullWeatherState is w.Loading || cityState is c.Loading,
        accentColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        onSubmitted: (newCityName) async {
          controller.close();

          final trimmedCityName = newCityName.trim();
          if (trimmedCityName.isEmpty) {
            return;
          }

          await cityStateNotifier.setCity(City(name: trimmedCityName));
          if (ref.read(c.cityStateNotifierProvider) is! c.Error) {
            await fullWeatherStateNotifier.loadFullWeather();
          }
```

I tried to check the documentation of the package but there was nothing related to that specific keyword. So I don't know what is the right keyword for it. Please someone help this out.